# defining relationship issue in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-migrations

How to define relationship between below tables.

```
Class->belongsToMany('Student');

Student->belongsToMany('Class');
```

Class table and Student table pivoted by class_student table

I have Payment table as below

```
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('class_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('student_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->integer('payment_amount');
        $table->timestamps();
        $table->softDeletes();
        $table->foreign('class_id')->references('id')->on('classes')->onDelete('cascade');
        $table->foreign('student_id')->references('id')->on('students')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Payment amount in the payment table means students can pay for each class tuition fee separately.

```
Payment has many students. And Payment has many Class.

Class has many Payments. And Class has many students.

Student has many Classs. And Student has many payments.
```

So how can I define many to many relationship without pivot table for Payment table? Or Should I create pivot table for class_payment_student table?

Comment: Define your relationships the other way around as well, with `->hasMany()`

Comment: Why are you need a many to many relationship for a payment? One payment belongs to one user and to one class, am I right? - as your migration says. But "Payment has many students?"

Answer (score 0):

You should create a pivot table payment_student.
If you want to pass the pivot table name you can pass it as second argument as below

Example:

```
return $this->belongsToMany("your_table_name", "pivot_table_name");
```